# What difference between "urllib.request.urlopen" and simple "open" for CSV handling

Tags: python, csv, encoding, urlopen, chardet

I'm re-reading old code of mine and I wonder why I used several times :

```
file_2_test = urllib.request.urlopen('file://' + file).read()
```

when (to my mind)

```
open(file)
```

would have been sufficient.

I couldn't find explanation anywhere. I suppose at this time I had to do this for a good reason but can't remember why.
The only clue I have is that each time, this line followed :

```
encoding = (chardet.detect(file_2_test))['encoding']
```

Could this line be a good reason I didn't use `open`?

Answer (score 1):

The two are different, [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) is a builtin python function and the [urlopen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) is a method of `request.urllib`

`open`: Open the **file** and return a corresponding file object. If the file cannot be opened, an `OSError` is raised.

`urlopen:`: Open the **URL**, which can be either a `string` or a `Request` object.

Comment: But is the result also different?

Comment: @Always Sunny : thanks for explanation
@ mkrieger1 : I suppose because I could handle the file the same way